# Sort list with None in Python getting the index

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, nonetype

How to sort a list with `None` value in Python getting the index?

```
myList=['BAT46ZFILM', 'CMD17-21VGD/TR8', 'BAT46ZFILM', None, 'B72207S2321K311']
```

I know that

```
[i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(myList), key=lambda x:x[1])]
```

get the index of the sort method. But how put all the `None` value at the end. For example, merging with this solution:

```
sorted(myList, key=lambda x: (x is None, x))
```

that sort with `None` value but do not get me the indexes.

Comment: What do you mean by "getting the index"? What is your expected output?

Comment: Please give expected output, the question is currently unclear.

Comment: Or maybe change `sorted(range(len(m)), key=lambda k: m[k])` to put `None`at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
sorted(range(len(m)), key=lambda k:(m[k] is None,  m[k]))
```

Comment: More explanation about what this code is doing would probably be helpful for OP...

Comment: Be my understanding of Python now. This code sort the vector of range give my vector `m` ( `[1,2,3,...]`), but to sort it use the `key` defined by the inline (`lambda`) function. In some way, when, in the iteration of the sort method, it found `None` it do not do the sort and keep `None`at the last.

Answer (score 0):

Combine both conditions (being a `None` and the string value) into tuples and sort by the tuples:

```
[i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(myList), key=lambda x:(x[1] is None, x[1]))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually sort with `None` (FYI)

```
>>> sorted([11, 33, 22, None])
[None, 11, 22, 33]
```

If you want to sort the values by removing `None`:

```
>>> a = [11, 33, 22, None]
>>> sorted([i for i in a if i is not None])
[11, 22, 33]
```

Comment: Thank, but I can not exclude `None`s. I tried some changes in `sorted` and `sorted(range(len(m)), key=lambda k:(m[k] is None,  m[k]))`worked.